# How to fire a function when timer reaches 0?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a short quiz game but I cant seem to figure it out. I feel like I have everything that I need, but I may have possibly placed them in a wrong order?

JS:

```
function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

function startTimer() {
    intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
        animations()
    }, 1000);
    time = 30;
}

animations = function() {
    time--;
    if (time >= 0) {
        timer.textContent = time;
    } else if (time == 0) {
        EndToAlert(); //*This is the function im trying to fire once timer 
        reaches 0 * //
            stopTimer();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What's happening instead? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: `} else if (time == 0) {` this line can't be reached, change to `} else if (time < 0) {`

Comment: ```time >= 0``` is true when ```time =0``` and so the time variable keeps going down. After 1 second you will have and ```time = -1``` so, it never reaches ```stopTimer()```.

Comment: Thanks Fei! changing it to  } else if (time < 0) { worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if (time == 0)` instead of `else if (time == 0)`, because when time=0, the `if (time >= 0)` above will be executed but the `else if (time == 0)` won’t.

Answer (score 0):

just change  else if (time == 0) to else.

Comment: This answer could be improved with a complete code snippet and an explanation of the problem and the solution.